# Deserializing Multidimensional array from JSON with ServiceStack fails

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, deserialization, servicestack-text

I have an object with a single `double[,]` property, which was serialized using ServiceStack `ToJson()` method as follows:

```
{"xy":[[-2.9774,-2.0682],[-1.1378,2.7118]]}
```

However I cannot deserialize it back to my object type (`Parameters`) using `"abovestring".FromJson<Parameters>()` as it throws the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Failed to set property 'xy' with '[[-2.9774,-2.0682],[-1.1378,2.7118]]' ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeBuiltin`1.<GetParseFn>b__a(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.JsReader`1.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<GetCoreParseFn>b__7(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeArrayWithElements`2.ParseGenericArray(String value, ParseStringDelegate elementParseFn)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeArray`2.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetParseFn>b__0(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType(TypeConfig typeConfig, String strType, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, Dictionary`2 typeAccessorMap)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeTypeRefJson.StringToType(TypeConfig typeConfig, String strType, EmptyCtorDelegate ctorFn, Dictionary`2 typeAccessorMap)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeType`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetParseMethod>b__1(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Json.JsonReader`1.Parse(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value)
   at ServiceStack.StringExtensions.FromJson[T](String json)
```

The target `Parameters` class is:

```
public class Parameters {
   public double[,] xy { get; set; }
}
```

If I change the property type to double[][] it works, but then I don't have roundtrip capabilities. It seems like ServiceStack is unable to deserialize to a multidimensional array ([,]) even though it should be able to see that this is the property's type.

It very much looks like an implementation bug, but it seems rather surprising given how basic this scenario is. Am I missing something?

Comment: `multidimensional` arrays are problematic. try jagged array or List of list.

Comment: Why would it be more problematic than a simple array of double?